# How to use jest.each asynchronously

Tags: node.js, async-await, jestjs

I am having problems loading filenames into jest.each asynchronously.

My code:

```js
let files: string[][]

function getFilesWorking() {
  files = [["test1"], ["test2"]]
}

async function getFilesAsync() {
  files = await Promise.resolve([["test1"], ["test2"]])
}

beforeAll(() => {
  console.log("before")
})

describe.only("Name of the group", () => {
  getFilesAsync()
  test.each(files)("runs", f => {})
})
```

beforeAll is executed before each test but NOT before initialization of test.each, so I end up with undefined.

How can I load files before using test.each?

Comment: you need to `await` your `getFilesAsync()` call

Comment: I can not pass an async function as cb to describe so I cannot await

Comment: Did you came up with the solution yet?

Comment: @Marecky Sorry, I don't remember!

Comment: Thanks for reply! No problem, It turned out my problem was in the tested code itself. I managed to test without async/await

Answer (score 2):

As of Jest `28.1.3` and prior, this is not possible.  There is an [open issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9709) documenting this behavior.

The best thing you can do for now is put your tests in a regular `it()` test and do a deep value comparison:

```
it('tests an array of cases', async () => {
  const data = await getSomeAsyncData()
  const expectedData = [ ... ]

  expect(data).toEqual(expectedData)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an `async` callback to `beforeAll` and `await getFilesAsync` within it

```
beforeAll(async () => {
  await getFilesAsync();
})
```

Comment: @mspoulsen yes, sorry, my bad I misunderstood the question. All of the test definitions must use static data

Comment: yeah...I realized that. Thanks ;)

Answer (score -2):

You can use `beforeEach` to set up code that will run prior to tests for any given scope, https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    console.log('before every test');
});

describe.only(('Name of the group') => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        console.log('before tests in this describe block');
    })
})
```

Jest is only going to run the tests in your `describe.only` block. If you want to use `beforeEach` in other blocks and run those tests as well, change `describe.only` to `describe`.

(Edit: I know this is a year late, I'm just trying to look for a similar problem/solution set and thought I could answer this.)